# Dynamic strings in C

Tags: c

Is this a good practice when dealing with dynamic strings?
In order words is it not going to generate "undefined behaviour"?

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Global Error Messaging
char *error_message;
void print_error(){
    printf("%s", error_message);
}

int main ()
{
    error_message = "Error";
    print_error();
    error_message = "Another Error";
    print_error();
    error_message = "Ops I did it again!";
    print_error();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Technically, no, it is not undefined behavior. Is it recommended, or good practice? Certainly not!

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: SO is a Q&A site, not a code review or discussion forum.

Comment: Pointers to string literals won't ever become invalid. If you'll only ever store those you're safe.

Comment: Plus, where are these "dynamic strings" the OP is referring to?

Comment: Thanks @PSkocik. Could you post answer? I would love to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointers to string literals won't ever become invalid. If you'll only ever store those you're safe.
(`char const*` should be the preferred type for storing pointers to string literals as you might get killed by the OS if you try to modify string literals).

Stringy stack arrays will become invalid once you leave the current scope and `malloc`ed strings will become invalid after you free them.

Global variables might not be a good idea in multithreaded contexts and are generally frowned upon, but they might make sense or even be necessary in certain cases (e.g., dealing with Unix signals).